# zmq cpp performance compared to the latency reported by `qperf`

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to figure out why the `qperf` reports latency (one way) `x` and REQ/REP  (roundtrip) reports something like `4x`. Any particular socket tweaking I have to do? Because if I just open socket, set TCP_NODELAY (which set in ZMQ by default) I get latency very close (for 1k buffers) to the number reported by `qperf`. However the ZMQ is lagging behind these numbers about 4-5 times
The ZMQ server

```
zmq::context_t context;
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);

socket.bind("tcp://*:5555");

while (true) {
    zmq::message_t request;

    //  Wait for next request from client
    socket.recv(&request);

    //  Send reply back to client
    zmq::message_t reply(5);
    memcpy(reply.data(), "World", 5);
    socket.send(reply);
}
```

The ZMQ client

```
zmq::context_t context;
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);

std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
socket.connect("tcp://my.host:5555");

const size_t cycles = 100'000;
double throughput = 0;

zmq::message_t reply;

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
vector<uint8_t> buff(MessageSize, 0);
for (auto i = 0ul; i < cycles; ++i) {
    zmq::message_t request(MessageSize);
    memcpy(request.data(), buff.data(), MessageSize);
    throughput += request.size();
    socket.send(request);
    //  Get the reply.
    socket.recv(&reply);
}
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
std::cout << "Latency: " << us / cycles << "us." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Througput: " << std::fixed << throughput / us * 1'000'000 / 1024 / 1024 << "MiB/s." << std::endl;
```

Both are essentially ZMQ examples provided here http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient
Some background, Linux, Ubuntu, GCC 7.3, static library provided by `vcpkg`, built locally, looks like they pull the master from github.

Comment: I think that's just par for the course with ZeroMQ.  The library introduces additional latency beyond what's inherent in the low level network I/O.

Comment: And whats about their claim they are as fast as TCP could be? Moreover, it is REQ/REP sockets, not some fancy XPUB or DEALER/BROKER when I can imagine what introduces additional latency (for additional feature set these sockets provide)

Comment: I'm not involved with the library, so I can only comment from personal experience.  That being said, I've found ZMQ to be dramatically over-hyped. I believe when they claim "high speed" (which has not been my experience), they mean throughput.

Comment: Did you find other library that does better in latency sensitive environment?

Comment: No.  Latency wasn't a particular concern for us when using ZMQ (and the rest of our code is based on hand written sockets stuff).

Comment: ZMQ introduce a small latency if you compare it to posix. The overhead is still very small compared to other MQ library and most of the times it is fast enough.  If you want something with more performance you could try `boost::asio` or `nanomsg`. Otherwise, just use POSIX socket

Comment: When the "small" latency is 200% of the naïve TCP implementation it is no go. I've tried nanomsg, no prodigy too, it gives more or less the same latency as ZMQ does. There is nothing compared to posix implementation when you poll on file descriptors, IMHO. Maybe, just maybe, it adds too much abstractions in the simplest case, that's why latency is so high, but implementing it just using raw sockets wasn't big deal. Unfortunately, we didn't have enough time to compare it with `boost::asio`